# Docker for Windows exits with code 127 when building image

Tags: docker, gradle, dockerfile

When I try to build this Docker-Image, I get the following error:

[image: Log]

```
FROM java:8

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8080

RUN ./gradlew build

CMD ./gradlew bootRun
```

When I just build the app with "gradlew build" it runs and when I try to run this Docker Image with a Mac, it works too, just not for windows

EDIT:

[image: RUN ls Image]

Comment: `No such file or directory`... You need to actually copy over the `gradlew` shell script

Comment: can you elaborate on this a bit further?

Comment: Please show the content of the build directory in windows. Add a `RUN ls` step before the Gradle commands... My point is that `ADD . /app` did not actually ADD an executable file named `./gradlew`, as the error says

Comment: edited it into the post

Comment: Hmm... Okay. Anyway, this not really a "proper" way to run a Java app. You typically build a JAR *outside of the container*, then copy it in and just run that

Comment: That is absolutely not the "proper" way to run a Java app. The whole point of Docker is to standardize your build AND run environment across systems. The "proper" way to run a Java app is to build it in a build container and run it in a JRE container. There are mutliple ways to accomplish this by searching for "java docker multi stage build" that aren't suited to a comment here but don't want to leave this unanswered for anyone that happens to see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great answer, but what I found is that when Windows mounts files into Docker from Windows, it leaves Windows-like line endings on the mounted files. A janky way to solve it in your Dockerfile would be to install dos2unix in the container and add a

```
RUN dos2unix gradlew
```

prior to executing your build process. Unfortunately, this is a TERRIBLE solution. Hopefully Docker for Windows on WSL2 that is supposed to release soon will solve this better but for now you are stuck with this janky solution.

Answer (score 0):

gradlew must be marked as executable.

`chmod +x gradlew`

Mac and Linux share permissions scheme but Windows  needs to use a virtual FS so it copies files with default permissions - 644 and you need 755.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, adding in the dockerfile, before `RUN ./gradlew lib:build`:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install dos2unix && \
    apt-get clean
RUN dos2unix gradlew
RUN chmod +x gradlew
RUN ./gradlew lib:build
```